# Gaussian notch filter in Python

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, gaussian

I'm trying to design a Gaussian notch filter in Python to remove periodic noise.I tried implementing the following formula:

[Gaussian Notch Filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKiwl.png)

And here is the code:

```
import numpy as np

def gaussian_bandpass_filter(image):
    image_array = np.array(image)
    #Fourier Transform
    fourier_transform = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(image_array)) 

    #Size of Image
    m = np.shape(fourier_transform)[0]
    n = np.shape(fourier_transform)[1]

    u = np.arange(m)
    v = np.arange(n)

    # Find the center
    u0 = int(m/2)
    v0 = int(n/2)

    # Bandwidth
    D0 = 10

    gaussian_filter = np.zeros(np.shape(fourier_transform))

    for x in u:
        for y in v:
            D1 = math.sqrt((x-m/2-u0)**2 + (y-n/2-v0)**2)
            D2 = math.sqrt((x-m/2+u0)**2 + (y-n/2+v0)**2)
            gaussian_filter[x][y] = 1 - math.exp(-0.5 * D1*D2/(D0**2))

    #Apply the filter
    fourier_transform = fourier_transform + gaussian_filter
    image_array = np.fft.ifft2(np.fft.ifftshift(fourier_transform))

    return image_array
```

this function is supposed to apply the Gaussian notch filter to an image and return the filtered image but it doesn't seem to work. I don't know where I went wrong with this (maybe I didn't understand the formula correctly?) so if anyone could help me I would really appreciate it.

**Edit:**

As an example, here is a [noisy image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USc6e.png).
Using the existing gaussian_filter function in scipy.ndimage library, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkzjG.png), which is acceptable.
But my function returns [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8R4oZ.png). (I'm using PIL.Image.fromarray function to convert array to image)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it does not work"?

Comment: Do you need to make your own or do you just want to filter some images?

Comment: @wwii - I'm doing this for an assignment. I have to implement my own gaussian notch filter without using pre-existing functions.